# How do I update a column with null values that exist for a similar primary key on Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, data-cleaning

For instance, for a nashville housing dataset, I am trying to fill in property addresses that are null entry but should be the same for unique ids. I am trying to create two tables and then update the null entries in one table column and try to fill them into the next.

I have the code for microsoft sql server but I am having trouble converting to to Oracle.

```
 Update a
 SET PropertyAddress = ISNULL(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
 From PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing a
 JOIN PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing b
  on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
  AND a.[UniqueID ] <> b.[UniqueID ]
    Where a.PropertyAddress is null
```

Here is a link to the nashville housing date set:

https://github.com/AlexTheAnalyst/PortfolioProjects/blob/main/Nashville%20Housing%20Data%20for%20Data%20Cleaning.xlsx

Comment: You don’t need the ISNULL function as that is catered for in the WHERE CLAUSE. You probably need to filter out any b records where PropertyAddress is null (there’s no point updating nulls with nulls). If your logic returns more than 1 b record for each a record this isn't going to work (or at least not deterministically) - which b record should be used for the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be able to do it using a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO NashvilleHousing dst
USING NashvilleHousing src
ON (
    dst.parcelid = src.parcelid
AND dst.uniqueid <> src.uniqueid
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    propertyaddress = src.propertyaddress
  WHERE  dst.propertyaddress IS NULL;
```

or a correlated sub-query in an `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE NashvilleHousing dst
SET propertyaddress = (
  SELECT src.propertyaddress
  FROM   NashvilleHousing src
  WHERE  dst.parcelid = src.parcelid
  AND    dst.uniqueid <> src.uniqueid
  AND    src.propertyaddress IS NOT NULL
  AND    ROWNUM = 1
)
WHERE propertyaddress IS NULL
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f751ae919a930c1883f72479173c9d3)*